# Is there an algorithm to solve number manipulation problems?

Tags: arithmetic, problem-solving, game-theory, arithmetic-functions

There are this kind of problems where, given a certain amount of the same numbers, it's needed to manipulate them with functions or operators in a way to get a certain result. It's allowed to glue numbers together to form a number, as well as putting a period to create a decimal.

**Example:** Manipulate three numbers $3$ to get $8$.
The answer is $\left(3!\div 3\right)^3=8$.

I wonder if there is a certain algorithm for this kind of problems to find out the least numbers required to get the certain result, or, even better, the strategy to get that result.

Comment: One algorithm is just to try every possible expression

Comment: ...other than just bruteforcing ^^ There are too much variations, and they are increasing with the amount of numbers, so optimized solution is preferred.

Comment: It depends on what functions are allowed.  With the successor function from Peano arithmetic it gets very easy, since $S(S(S(S(S(3)))))=8$ and you can use the spare two $3$s for decoration